# Custom validator is not throwing the exact error message

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Custom validator is not throwing the exact error message.

I have written my custom validator and expecting that whenever i pass

name as [] or "" It should throw the valid error which I defined.

this I am actually doing which I want to change through validator

```
if (myRequestResult.getName() == null || myRequestResult.getName().isEmpty()) {
    throw exceiption ()
 }else{
    myService.setName(myRequestResult.getName())
 }
```

This is my validator

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = TestNameValidator.class)
public @interface ValidTestNames {

  String message() default "Name cannot be null or empty";

  Class<?>[] groups() default {};

  Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

and Implementation

```
public class TestNameValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidTestNames, List<String>> {

  private String message;

  @Override
  public void initialize(ValidTestNames constraintAnnotation) {
    this.message = constraintAnnotation.message();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(List<String> ValidTestNames, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {

    if (ValidTestNames == null || ValidTestNames.isEmpty() || ValidTestNames.stream().anyMatch(String::isBlank)) {
      System.out.println("Validation failed. Custom error message: " + message);
      context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
      context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(message)
        .addConstraintViolation();
      return false;
    } else {
      List<String> nonBlankNames = ValidTestNames.stream().filter(s -> !s.isBlank()).collect(Collectors.toList());
      if (nonBlankNames.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Validation failed. Custom error message: " + message);
        context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
        context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(message)
          .addConstraintViolation();
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

}
```

here is my controller

```
@Log4j2
@RestController(value = "apiMyController")
@Validated
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/v1/someRandomeURL")
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__({@Autowired}))
public class ExecutionResultsController {
  
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public ExecutionResultDTO create(@RequestBody @Valid MyRequestResult myRequestResult) throws Exception {
    
     myService.setName(myRequestResult.getName());
  }
}
```

and in MyRequestResult I have given the value like this

```
  @ValidTestNames
  public List<String> name
```

Now it is working as if I pass the value it is setting up the name value but when I pass

1. empty [] it is executing as name setting up [] it should throw error
2. "" when i pass this it is giving 400 with error message.

what wnet wrong here and how should i fix.

Comment: why -1 As per the SOF i have tried while reading the doc. I got stuck so I have asked is this correct way to do or not

Comment: For starters remove `@Validated` from the controller that is for somethingt totally different. What are you sending? Request parameters or json or something else? What is being bound?

Comment: "" is an empty string not an empty array and thus wouldn't bind to your object, not even leading to be able to validate it. You have a binding error and not a validation error in this case.

Comment: even If i remove `@Validated` from the controller that controller result is same, so I was trying it by putting in controller. "" empty string check I have given in my validator implementation. My break point itself is not going there.

Comment: I can directly do that chack by using `if` statemnt but want to do through validator. @M.Deinum any article you can suggest for this

Comment: What do you mean with `if` statement? An empty string doesn't convert to a list, hence is a data binding issue, you don't even reach validation so validation won't work for `""` as the data simply doesn't match. You are basically stating, I have a field of type `int` I send `foobar` as a value and I want to validate with a validator if it is a valid integer. That simply won't work as `foobar` is a String and not a valid value for an `int`. The same for `""` for a list. It isn't.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have update the question how I was using if and then this how I changed to validator.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that "" simply won't bind, no binding (or binding error in this case) skips validation.

Comment: @M.Deinum What I got that i need to bind error in both the case of `[]` and `""`.

i am following this article https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator and in my `isValid` method i am doing the check any link or way you can suggest how to bind error.

Comment: It will not reach your validator, because it cannot contruct the object. It will neve rhappen. I'm going to leave it at that.

Comment: I'm curious, why are you using a Custom Validator and not the existent `@NotBlank`?

Comment: @DjaneLuz so I can make use of other places to

Comment: You can use `@NotBlank` in other places too. Can you post your Unit Test class?